# intellij idea различия community и ultimate версии

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Подскажите какие различия и какими средствами Idea реализует отличия версий.

Ну например:

Поддержа Spring в Ultimate.

В community блокируется сборка проектов со Spring, или Idea просто не дает подсказки по Spring?
Ну или еще что нить.

Так же с hibernate.

Comment: Вы читали, что перед тем как задать вопрос, нужно постараться самостоятельно решить проблему? Подробнейший ответ на ваш вопрос находится в два клика. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых это поддержка плагинов. Много чего не доступно на community. Во вторых Вы верно говорите, работа со Spring невозможна, так как сам проект просто не соберется, подсказки тут не причем. Что касается Hibernate и Jpa, то тут все аналогично, порабоьать с ними не получится. И конечно же нет такой поддержки при работе со сборщиками и git, хотя какие-то базовые вещи доступны. Community версия она скорее для Core, для Enterprise-разработки лучше брать ultimate. Тем более для студентов, преподавателей и некоторых бюджетников она бесплатна.

Comment: Я спокойно собирал проект на Spring с community версией. Hibernate и Jpa также работали. Возможно, вы имеете в виду какие-то необязательные подсказки и дополнительные кнопки, которые появляются в Ultimate версии?

Comment: Ну, например, со Swagger Вы уже не поработаете, отсутствуют так же много фичей по БД. Собрать, в принципе, можно и на community, но насколько это будет удобно при работе с боевыми проектами...